# Checking Data from a Controller on Button Click?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm new to Ruby, but I have created a quiz-like site where users answer multiple-choice questions. Each question is assigned to a particular quiz, so there could be multiple questions for each quiz. I'm stumped at trying to see whether the choice selected is correct for that answer or not. All the answers were saved with a `question_id` referrer and a `correct` boolean.

I have a feeling it has something to do with `link_to`, but I can't figure it out.

Here is the controller I am accessing:

```
def check
        puts "//////// //////// /////// #{@givenAnswer}"
        puts "//////// //////// /////// #{@correctAnswer}"
end
```

Here is as near as I can get to making it work, but I get a Url error:

```
<%= link_to "#{@ans.content}", {:controller=>:pages,:action=>:check, :givenAnswer=>@ans.content, :correctAnswer=>params["correct#{@q.id}"]}, :method=>:get, :class => "btn" %>
```

The above gives a `UrlGenerationError`.

Both `@q` and `@ans` are created by loops in the script. They are defined properly.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. As per syntax given by you for link_to you are missing closing '}' before :method option.
2. As long as pages controller is not under some namespace then it should generate the correct link and should not give url error.
3. In check action correctAnswer and givenAnswer will be available in params hash and not directly as @givenAnswer and @correctAnswer. Please see params hash in check action.